# How to align long array?

Tags: arrays

I use *Mathematica* and the command `TeXForm` to convert Equation. The array is too long. I try to find a way but I can't align this equation. How can I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-5,8,0\} &\{-3,-6,4\} \\
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-3,-6,4\} &\{7,-4,6\} \\
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-3,6,10\} &\{4,8,9\} \\
 \{-7,-2,4\} & \{-5,8,6\} & \{-3,-6,2\} \\
 \{-7,-2,4\} & \{-3,-6,2\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-7,3,-1\} & \{-3,-5,7\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{-7,3,7\} & \{-3,-5,-1\} &\{-2,8,9\} \\
 \{-7,6,2\} & \{-5,-4,0\} &\{-3,10,4\} \\
 \{-7,6,2\} & \{-3,-2,10\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{-7,6,4\} & \{-3,10,2\} &\{7,8,0\} \\
 \{-6,-2,-1\} & \{2,6,-5\} &\{7,8,0\} \\
 \{-6,-2,7\} & \{-5,-4,0\} &\{2,6,11\} \\
 \{-6,6,-1\} & \{2,-2,-5\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-6,6,7\} & \{-5,8,0\} &\{2,-2,11\} \\
 \{-5,-4,0\} & \{5,-6,2\} &\{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{-5,-4,6\} & \{-3,1,11\} &\{5,9,7\} \\
 \{-5,-4,6\} & \{5,-6,4\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{-5,-1,9\} & \{-3,-6,4\} &\{5,-2,-4\} \\
 \{-5,5,-3\} & \{0,10,-1\} &\{8,6,7\} \\
 \{-5,5,9\} & \{0,10,7\} &\{8,6,-1\} \\
 \{-5,8,0\} & \{-3,9,7\} &\{5,1,11\} \\
 \{-5,8,0\} & \{5,10,2\} & \{9,6,4\} \\
 \{-3,-2,-4\} & \{5,-6,4\} &\{7,-1,9\} \\
 \{-3,1,-5\} & \{5,9,-1\} &\{7,8,6\} \\
 \{-3,9,-1\} & \{5,1,-5\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-2,-4,-3\} & \{0,6,-5\} &\{2,10,-1\} \\
 \{-2,-4,-3\} & \{5,-5,-1\} &\{9,3,7\} \\
 \{-2,-4,9\} & \{0,6,11\} &\{2,10,7\} \\
 \{-2,8,-3\} & \{0,10,7\} &\{2,6,11\} \\
 \{-2,8,9\} & \{0,10,-1\} &\{2,6,-5\} \\
 \{0,-6,-1\} & \{2,-2,-5\} & \{4,8,-3\} \\
 \{0,-6,7\} & \{2,-2,11\} &\{4,8,9\} \\
 \{0,-2,-5\} & \{2,-6,-1\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{0,-2,11\} & \{2,-6,7\} &\{4,-4,-3\} \\
 \{0,6,-5\} & \{2,10,-1\} & \{4,8,9\} \\
 \{0,6,11\} & \{2,10,7\} & \{4,8,-3\} \\
 \{0,10,-1\} & \{2,6,-5\} & \{4,-4,-3\} \\
 \{0,10,7\} & \{2,6,11\} & \{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{4,-4,-3\} & \{5,6,10\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-5,7\} &\{9,3,-1\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-2,10\} & \{9,6,2\} \\
 \{5,-6,2\} & \{7,8,6\} &\{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{5,-6,4\} & \{7,8,0\} &\{9,-2,2\} \\
\{5,10,4\} & \{7,-4,0\} &\{9,6,2\} \\
 \{0,10,7\} & \{2,6,11\} & \{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{4,-4,-3\} & \{5,6,10\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-5,7\} & \{9,3,-1\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-2,10\} &\{9,6,2\} \\
 \{5,-6,2\} & \{7,8,6\} & \{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{5,-6,4\} & \{7,8,0\} &\{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{5,10,4\} & \{7,-4,0\} &\{9,6,2\}
\end{array}
\right)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the single values (e.g. 7, 5, ...) to be aligned, or you want simply the triples to be aligned left or right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\small\[
\left(\begin{array}{*{3}{r@{,}r@{,}r}}
 \{-7&-2&2\} & \{-5&8&0\} &\{-3&-6&4\} \\
 \{-7&-2&2\} & \{-3&-6&4\} &\{7&-4&6\} \\
 \{-7&-2&2\} & \{-3&6&10\} &\{4&8&9\} \\
 \{-7&-2&4\} & \{-5&8&6\} & \{-3&-6&2\} \\
 \{-7&-2&4\} & \{-3&-6&2\} &\{7&-4&0\} \\
 \{-7&3&-1\} & \{-3&-5&7\} &\{4&-4&9\} \\
 \{-7&3&7\} & \{-3&-5&-1\} &\{-2&8&9\} \\
 \{-7&6&2\} & \{-5&-4&0\} &\{-3&10&4\} \\
 \{-7&6&2\} & \{-3&-2&10\} &\{4&-4&9\} \\
 \{-7&6&4\} & \{-3&10&2\} &\{7&8&0\} \\
 \{-6&-2&-1\} & \{2&6&-5\} &\{7&8&0\} \\
 \{-6&-2&7\} & \{-5&-4&0\} &\{2&6&11\} \\
 \{-6&6&-1\} & \{2&-2&-5\} &\{7&-4&0\} \\
 \{-6&6&7\} & \{-5&8&0\} &\{2&-2&11\} \\
 \{-5&-4&0\} & \{5&-6&2\} &\{9&-2&4\} \\
 \{-5&-4&6\} & \{-3&1&11\} &\{5&9&7\} \\
 \{-5&-4&6\} & \{5&-6&4\} & \{9&-2&2\} \\
 \{-5&-1&9\} & \{-3&-6&4\} &\{5&-2&-4\} \\
 \{-5&5&-3\} & \{0&10&-1\} &\{8&6&7\} \\
 \{-5&5&9\} & \{0&10&7\} &\{8&6&-1\} \\
 \{-5&8&0\} & \{-3&9&7\} &\{5&1&11\} \\
 \{-5&8&0\} & \{5&10&2\} & \{9&6&4\} \\
 \{-3&-2&-4\} & \{5&-6&4\} &\{7&-1&9\} \\
 \{-3&1&-5\} & \{5&9&-1\} &\{7&8&6\} \\
 \{-3&9&-1\} & \{5&1&-5\} &\{7&-4&0\} \\
 \{-2&-4&-3\} & \{0&6&-5\} &\{2&10&-1\} \\
 \{-2&-4&-3\} & \{5&-5&-1\} &\{9&3&7\} \\
 \{-2&-4&9\} & \{0&6&11\} &\{2&10&7\} \\
 \{-2&8&-3\} & \{0&10&7\} &\{2&6&11\} \\
 \{-2&8&9\} & \{0&10&-1\} &\{2&6&-5\} \\
 \{0&-6&-1\} & \{2&-2&-5\} & \{4&8&-3\} \\
 \{0&-6&7\} & \{2&-2&11\} &\{4&8&9\} \\
 \{0&-2&-5\} & \{2&-6&-1\} &\{4&-4&9\} \\
 \{0&-2&11\} & \{2&-6&7\} &\{4&-4&-3\} \\
 \{0&6&-5\} & \{2&10&-1\} & \{4&8&9\} \\
 \{0&6&11\} & \{2&10&7\} & \{4&8&-3\} \\
 \{0&10&-1\} & \{2&6&-5\} & \{4&-4&-3\} \\
 \{0&10&7\} & \{2&6&11\} & \{4&-4&9\} \\
 \{4&-4&-3\} & \{5&6&10\} & \{9&-2&2\} \\
 \{4&8&-3\} & \{5&-5&7\} &\{9&3&-1\} \\
 \{4&8&-3\} & \{5&-2&10\} & \{9&6&2\} \\
 \{5&-6&2\} & \{7&8&6\} &\{9&-2&4\} \\
 \{5&-6&4\} & \{7&8&0\} &\{9&-2&2\} \\
\{5&10&4\} & \{7&-4&0\} &\{9&6&2\} \\
 \{0&10&7\} & \{2&6&11\} & \{4&-4&9\} \\
 \{4&-4&-3\} & \{5&6&10\} & \{9&-2&2\} \\
 \{4&8&-3\} & \{5&-5&7\} & \{9&3&-1\} \\
 \{4&8&-3\} & \{5&-2&10\} &\{9&6&2\} \\
 \{5&-6&2\} & \{7&8&6\} & \{9&-2&4\} \\
 \{5&-6&4\} & \{7&8&0\} &\{9&-2&2\} \\
 \{5&10&4\} & \{7&-4&0\} &\{9&6&2\}
\end{array}\right)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to define a delimited macro, say `\3{#1,#2,#3}` that would expand to format the triple?  if the way the columns are shown in the question is the way they come out of mathematica, it would mean a lot less hand editing.  (although a global replacement of all commas with `&`s would shorten that considerably.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton as you know anything's possible:-) although actually I think adding `\3` is a more involved edit than simply globally replacing `,` by `&` which is all I did here

Answer (score 6):

Here are two approaches depending on your needs.  Each needs hand editing of the output.  Results and full code are shown at the bottom.

## Approach 1

As the whole expression is enclosed in parentheses there is not standard way to do this.  I suggest you describe the matrix as

```
X = ( X_1 )
    ( X_2 )
```

where X_1 and X_2 are smaller submatrices that will fit in the space available.  Now insert `X_1 =` before the `\left(\begin{array}` and insert

```
\end{array}\right)\]
and 
\[ X_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
```

at a place appropriate for the page break.

(An alternative, would be to place the definitions of X_1 and X_2 in floating environments such as `table` and reference those `table`s.  Then you would just have to make sure each X_i is smaller than one page.)

## Approach 2

If the parentheses are not important, then you can either use the `longtable` package, or `mdframed`.  Neither will need choosing the page break by hand.  Here is an `mdframed` approach.  Replace the `\[\left(\array{ccc}' and`\end{array}\right)]` by

```
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true]
\allowdisplaybreaks 
\begin{align*}
```

and

```
\end{align*}
\end{mdframed}
```

and replace each `&` by `&&`.

## Result of approach 1

[image: version 1 page 1]

[image: version 1 page 2]

## Result of approach 2

[image: version 2 page 1]

[image: version 2 page 2]

## Code for approach 1

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{equation*}
  X =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    X_1 \\ X_2
  \end{pmatrix}
  ,
\end{equation*}
where
\[
X_1 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-5,8,0\} &\{-3,-6,4\} \\
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-3,-6,4\} &\{7,-4,6\} \\
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-3,6,10\} &\{4,8,9\} \\
 \{-7,-2,4\} & \{-5,8,6\} & \{-3,-6,2\} \\
 \{-7,-2,4\} & \{-3,-6,2\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-7,3,-1\} & \{-3,-5,7\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{-7,3,7\} & \{-3,-5,-1\} &\{-2,8,9\} \\
 \{-7,6,2\} & \{-5,-4,0\} &\{-3,10,4\} \\
 \{-7,6,2\} & \{-3,-2,10\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{-7,6,4\} & \{-3,10,2\} &\{7,8,0\} \\
 \{-6,-2,-1\} & \{2,6,-5\} &\{7,8,0\} \\
 \{-6,-2,7\} & \{-5,-4,0\} &\{2,6,11\} \\
 \{-6,6,-1\} & \{2,-2,-5\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-6,6,7\} & \{-5,8,0\} &\{2,-2,11\} \\
 \{-5,-4,0\} & \{5,-6,2\} &\{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{-5,-4,6\} & \{-3,1,11\} &\{5,9,7\} \\
 \{-5,-4,6\} & \{5,-6,4\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{-5,-1,9\} & \{-3,-6,4\} &\{5,-2,-4\} \\
 \{-5,5,-3\} & \{0,10,-1\} &\{8,6,7\} \\
 \{-5,5,9\} & \{0,10,7\} &\{8,6,-1\} \\
 \{-5,8,0\} & \{-3,9,7\} &\{5,1,11\} \\
 \{-5,8,0\} & \{5,10,2\} & \{9,6,4\} \\
 \{-3,-2,-4\} & \{5,-6,4\} &\{7,-1,9\} \\
 \{-3,1,-5\} & \{5,9,-1\} &\{7,8,6\} \\
 \{-3,9,-1\} & \{5,1,-5\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-2,-4,-3\} & \{0,6,-5\} &\{2,10,-1\}\\
\{-2,-4,-3\} & \{5,-5,-1\} &\{9,3,7\} \\
 \{-2,-4,9\} & \{0,6,11\} &\{2,10,7\} \\
 \{-2,8,-3\} & \{0,10,7\} &\{2,6,11\} \\
 \{-2,8,9\} & \{0,10,-1\} &\{2,6,-5\} \\
 \{0,-6,-1\} & \{2,-2,-5\} & \{4,8,-3\} \\
\end{array}\right)\]
and 
\[ X_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{0,-6,7\} & \{2,-2,11\} &\{4,8,9\} \\
 \{0,-2,-5\} & \{2,-6,-1\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{0,-2,11\} & \{2,-6,7\} &\{4,-4,-3\} \\
 \{0,6,-5\} & \{2,10,-1\} & \{4,8,9\} \\
 \{0,6,11\} & \{2,10,7\} & \{4,8,-3\} \\
 \{0,10,-1\} & \{2,6,-5\} & \{4,-4,-3\} \\
 \{0,10,7\} & \{2,6,11\} & \{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{4,-4,-3\} & \{5,6,10\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-5,7\} &\{9,3,-1\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-2,10\} & \{9,6,2\} \\
 \{5,-6,2\} & \{7,8,6\} &\{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{5,-6,4\} & \{7,8,0\} &\{9,-2,2\} \\
\{5,10,4\} & \{7,-4,0\} &\{9,6,2\} \\
 \{0,10,7\} & \{2,6,11\} & \{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{4,-4,-3\} & \{5,6,10\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-5,7\} & \{9,3,-1\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-2,10\} &\{9,6,2\} \\
 \{5,-6,2\} & \{7,8,6\} & \{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{5,-6,4\} & \{7,8,0\} &\{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{5,10,4\} & \{7,-4,0\} &\{9,6,2\}
\end{array}
\right)\]
\end{document}
```

## Code for approach 2

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true]
\allowdisplaybreaks 
\begin{align*}
  \{-7,-2,2\} && \{-5,8,0\} &&\{-3,-6,4\} \\
  \{-7,-2,2\} && \{-3,-6,4\} &&\{7,-4,6\} \\
  \{-7,-2,2\} && \{-3,6,10\} &&\{4,8,9\} \\
  \{-7,-2,4\} && \{-5,8,6\} && \{-3,-6,2\} \\
  \{-7,-2,4\} && \{-3,-6,2\} &&\{7,-4,0\} \\
  \{-7,3,-1\} && \{-3,-5,7\} &&\{4,-4,9\} \\
  \{-7,3,7\} && \{-3,-5,-1\} &&\{-2,8,9\} \\
  \{-7,6,2\} && \{-5,-4,0\} &&\{-3,10,4\} \\
  \{-7,6,2\} && \{-3,-2,10\} &&\{4,-4,9\} \\
  \{-7,6,4\} && \{-3,10,2\} &&\{7,8,0\} \\
  \{-6,-2,-1\} && \{2,6,-5\} &&\{7,8,0\} \\
  \{-6,-2,7\} && \{-5,-4,0\} &&\{2,6,11\} \\
  \{-6,6,-1\} && \{2,-2,-5\} &&\{7,-4,0\} \\
  \{-6,6,7\} && \{-5,8,0\} &&\{2,-2,11\} \\
  \{-5,-4,0\} && \{5,-6,2\} &&\{9,-2,4\} \\
  \{-5,-4,6\} && \{-3,1,11\} &&\{5,9,7\} \\
  \{-5,-4,6\} && \{5,-6,4\} && \{9,-2,2\} \\
  \{-5,-1,9\} && \{-3,-6,4\} &&\{5,-2,-4\} \\
  \{-5,5,-3\} && \{0,10,-1\} &&\{8,6,7\} \\
  \{-5,5,9\} && \{0,10,7\} &&\{8,6,-1\} \\
  \{-5,8,0\} && \{-3,9,7\} &&\{5,1,11\} \\
  \{-5,8,0\} && \{5,10,2\} && \{9,6,4\} \\
  \{-3,-2,-4\} && \{5,-6,4\} &&\{7,-1,9\} \\
  \{-3,1,-5\} && \{5,9,-1\} &&\{7,8,6\} \\
  \{-3,9,-1\} && \{5,1,-5\} &&\{7,-4,0\} \\
  \{-2,-4,-3\} && \{0,6,-5\} &&\{2,10,-1\}\\
  \{-2,-4,-3\} && \{5,-5,-1\} &&\{9,3,7\} \\
  \{-2,-4,9\} && \{0,6,11\} &&\{2,10,7\} \\
  \{-2,8,-3\} && \{0,10,7\} &&\{2,6,11\} \\
  \{-2,8,9\} && \{0,10,-1\} &&\{2,6,-5\} \\
  \{0,-6,-1\} && \{2,-2,-5\} && \{4,8,-3\} \\
  \{0,-6,7\} && \{2,-2,11\} &&\{4,8,9\} \\
  \{0,-2,-5\} && \{2,-6,-1\} &&\{4,-4,9\} \\
  \{0,-2,11\} && \{2,-6,7\} &&\{4,-4,-3\} \\
  \{0,6,-5\} && \{2,10,-1\} && \{4,8,9\} \\
  \{0,6,11\} && \{2,10,7\} && \{4,8,-3\} \\
  \{0,10,-1\} && \{2,6,-5\} && \{4,-4,-3\} \\
  \{0,10,7\} && \{2,6,11\} && \{4,-4,9\} \\
  \{4,-4,-3\} && \{5,6,10\} && \{9,-2,2\} \\
  \{4,8,-3\} && \{5,-5,7\} &&\{9,3,-1\} \\
  \{4,8,-3\} && \{5,-2,10\} && \{9,6,2\} \\
  \{5,-6,2\} && \{7,8,6\} &&\{9,-2,4\} \\
  \{5,-6,4\} && \{7,8,0\} &&\{9,-2,2\} \\
  \{5,10,4\} && \{7,-4,0\} &&\{9,6,2\} \\
  \{0,10,7\} && \{2,6,11\} && \{4,-4,9\} \\
  \{4,-4,-3\} && \{5,6,10\} && \{9,-2,2\} \\
  \{4,8,-3\} && \{5,-5,7\} && \{9,3,-1\} \\
  \{4,8,-3\} && \{5,-2,10\} &&\{9,6,2\} \\
  \{5,-6,2\} && \{7,8,6\} && \{9,-2,4\} \\
  \{5,-6,4\} && \{7,8,0\} &&\{9,-2,2\} \\
  \{5,10,4\} && \{7,-4,0\} &&\{9,6,2\}\\
\end{align*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `longtable` environment with nine columns. Each column is processed automatically processed in math mode, and curly braces and commas are inserted automatically. Because a `longtable` can break across pages, you don't have to worry about allowing (or disallowing...) page breaks just to make the array fit on a page.

The first half dozen rows of the resulting array look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier,longtable,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| *{3}{>{$\{}r<{$} @{,\,} >{$}r<{$} @{,\,} >{$}r<{\}$} } |}
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page
\multicolumn{9}{l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}
\endhead
\multicolumn{9}{r}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot  % blank footer on final page
 -7 & -2 & 2 & -5 & 8 & 0 &-3 & -6 & 4 \\
 -7 & -2 & 2 & -3 & -6 & 4 &7 & -4 & 6 \\
 -7 & -2 & 2 & -3 & 6 & 10 &4 & 8 & 9 \\
 -7 & -2 & 4 & -5 & 8 & 6 & -3 & -6 & 2 \\
 -7 & -2 & 4 & -3 & -6 & 2 &7 & -4 & 0 \\
 -7 & 3 & -1 & -3 & -5 & 7 &4 & -4 & 9 \\
 -7 & 3 & 7 & -3 & -5 & -1 &-2 & 8 & 9 \\
 -7 & 6 & 2 & -5 & -4 & 0 &-3 & 10 & 4 \\
 -7 & 6 & 2 & -3 & -2 & 10 &4 & -4 & 9 \\
 -7 & 6 & 4 & -3 & 10 & 2 &7 & 8 & 0 \\
 -6 & -2 & -1 & 2 & 6 & -5 &7 & 8 & 0 \\
 -6 & -2 & 7 & -5 & -4 & 0 &2 & 6 & 11 \\
 -6 & 6 & -1 & 2 & -2 & -5 &7 & -4 & 0 \\
 -6 & 6 & 7 & -5 & 8 & 0 &2 & -2 & 11 \\
 -5 & -4 & 0 & 5 & -6 & 2 &9 & -2 & 4 \\
 -5 & -4 & 6 & -3 & 1 & 11 &5 & 9 & 7 \\
 -5 & -4 & 6 & 5 & -6 & 4 & 9 & -2 & 2 \\
 -5 & -1 & 9 & -3 & -6 & 4 &5 & -2 & -4 \\
 -5 & 5 & -3 & 0 & 10 & -1 &8 & 6 & 7 \\
 -5 & 5 & 9 & 0 & 10 & 7 &8 & 6 & -1 \\
 -5 & 8 & 0 & -3 & 9 & 7 &5 & 1 & 11 \\
 -5 & 8 & 0 & 5 & 10 & 2 & 9 & 6 & 4 \\
 -3 & -2 & -4 & 5 & -6 & 4 &7 & -1 & 9 \\
 -3 & 1 & -5 & 5 & 9 & -1 &7 & 8 & 6 \\
 -3 & 9 & -1 & 5 & 1 & -5 &7 & -4 & 0 \\
 -2 & -4 & -3 & 0 & 6 & -5 &2 & 10 & -1 \\
 -2 & -4 & -3 & 5 & -5 & -1 &9 & 3 & 7 \\
 -2 & -4 & 9 & 0 & 6 & 11 &2 & 10 & 7 \\
 -2 & 8 & -3 & 0 & 10 & 7 &2 & 6 & 11 \\
 -2 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 10 & -1 &2 & 6 & -5 \\
 0 & -6 & -1 & 2 & -2 & -5 & 4 & 8 & -3 \\
 0 & -6 & 7 & 2 & -2 & 11 &4 & 8 & 9 \\
 0 & -2 & -5 & 2 & -6 & -1 &4 & -4 & 9 \\
 0 & -2 & 11 & 2 & -6 & 7 &4 & -4 & -3 \\
 0 & 6 & -5 & 2 & 10 & -1 & 4 & 8 & 9 \\
 0 & 6 & 11 & 2 & 10 & 7 & 4 & 8 & -3 \\
 0 & 10 & -1 & 2 & 6 & -5 & 4 & -4 & -3 \\
 0 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 11 & 4 & -4 & 9 \\
 4 & -4 & -3 & 5 & 6 & 10 & 9 & -2 & 2 \\
 4 & 8 & -3 & 5 & -5 & 7 &9 & 3 & -1 \\
 4 & 8 & -3 & 5 & -2 & 10 & 9 & 6 & 2 \\
 5 & -6 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 6 &9 & -2 & 4 \\
 5 & -6 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 0 &9 & -2 & 2 \\
 5 & 10 & 4 & 7 & -4 & 0 &9 & 6 & 2 \\
 0 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 11 & 4 & -4 & 9 \\
 4 & -4 & -3 & 5 & 6 & 10 & 9 & -2 & 2 \\
 4 & 8 & -3 & 5 & -5 & 7 & 9 & 3 & -1 \\
 4 & 8 & -3 & 5 & -2 & 10 &9 & 6 & 2 \\
 5 & -6 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 9 & -2 & 4 \\
 5 & -6 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 0 &9 & -2 & 2 \\
 5 & 10 & 4 & 7 & -4 & 0 &9 & 6 & 2 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you choose to keep the code of the body of the array the way it's provided by Mathematica, you can still use a `longtable` environment instead of an `array` environment to typeset the material. Just replace the current instruction

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
```

with

```
\begin{longtable}{| *{3}{>{$}c<{$}} | }
```

If a page break occurs somewhere in the array, you could provide the following code to guide the reader's eye:

```
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot  % blank footer on final page
```

The material on the second page would look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| *{3}{>{$}c<{$}} | }
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot  % blank footer on final page
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-5,8,0\} &\{-3,-6,4\} \\
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-3,-6,4\} &\{7,-4,6\} \\
 \{-7,-2,2\} & \{-3,6,10\} &\{4,8,9\} \\
 \{-7,-2,4\} & \{-5,8,6\} & \{-3,-6,2\} \\
 \{-7,-2,4\} & \{-3,-6,2\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-7,3,-1\} & \{-3,-5,7\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{-7,3,7\} & \{-3,-5,-1\} &\{-2,8,9\} \\
 \{-7,6,2\} & \{-5,-4,0\} &\{-3,10,4\} \\
 \{-7,6,2\} & \{-3,-2,10\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{-7,6,4\} & \{-3,10,2\} &\{7,8,0\} \\
 \{-6,-2,-1\} & \{2,6,-5\} &\{7,8,0\} \\
 \{-6,-2,7\} & \{-5,-4,0\} &\{2,6,11\} \\
 \{-6,6,-1\} & \{2,-2,-5\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-6,6,7\} & \{-5,8,0\} &\{2,-2,11\} \\
 \{-5,-4,0\} & \{5,-6,2\} &\{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{-5,-4,6\} & \{-3,1,11\} &\{5,9,7\} \\
 \{-5,-4,6\} & \{5,-6,4\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{-5,-1,9\} & \{-3,-6,4\} &\{5,-2,-4\} \\
 \{-5,5,-3\} & \{0,10,-1\} &\{8,6,7\} \\
 \{-5,5,9\} & \{0,10,7\} &\{8,6,-1\} \\
 \{-5,8,0\} & \{-3,9,7\} &\{5,1,11\} \\
 \{-5,8,0\} & \{5,10,2\} & \{9,6,4\} \\
 \{-3,-2,-4\} & \{5,-6,4\} &\{7,-1,9\} \\
 \{-3,1,-5\} & \{5,9,-1\} &\{7,8,6\} \\
 \{-3,9,-1\} & \{5,1,-5\} &\{7,-4,0\} \\
 \{-2,-4,-3\} & \{0,6,-5\} &\{2,10,-1\} \\
 \{-2,-4,-3\} & \{5,-5,-1\} &\{9,3,7\} \\
 \{-2,-4,9\} & \{0,6,11\} &\{2,10,7\} \\
 \{-2,8,-3\} & \{0,10,7\} &\{2,6,11\} \\
 \{-2,8,9\} & \{0,10,-1\} &\{2,6,-5\} \\
 \{0,-6,-1\} & \{2,-2,-5\} & \{4,8,-3\} \\
 \{0,-6,7\} & \{2,-2,11\} &\{4,8,9\} \\
 \{0,-2,-5\} & \{2,-6,-1\} &\{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{0,-2,11\} & \{2,-6,7\} &\{4,-4,-3\} \\
 \{0,6,-5\} & \{2,10,-1\} & \{4,8,9\} \\
 \{0,6,11\} & \{2,10,7\} & \{4,8,-3\} \\
 \{0,10,-1\} & \{2,6,-5\} & \{4,-4,-3\} \\
 \{0,10,7\} & \{2,6,11\} & \{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{4,-4,-3\} & \{5,6,10\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-5,7\} &\{9,3,-1\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-2,10\} & \{9,6,2\} \\
 \{5,-6,2\} & \{7,8,6\} &\{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{5,-6,4\} & \{7,8,0\} &\{9,-2,2\} \\
\{5,10,4\} & \{7,-4,0\} &\{9,6,2\} \\
 \{0,10,7\} & \{2,6,11\} & \{4,-4,9\} \\
 \{4,-4,-3\} & \{5,6,10\} & \{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-5,7\} & \{9,3,-1\} \\
 \{4,8,-3\} & \{5,-2,10\} &\{9,6,2\} \\
 \{5,-6,2\} & \{7,8,6\} & \{9,-2,4\} \\
 \{5,-6,4\} & \{7,8,0\} &\{9,-2,2\} \\
 \{5,10,4\} & \{7,-4,0\} &\{9,6,2\}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico. Thank you for your answer. But, I must repair code from Mathematica (add & many times).

Comment: @minthao_2011 - I've provided an addendum to show how to use a `longtable` environment while keeping the bulk of the array code provided by Mathematica.

Comment: If I have 4 columns, how can I change the code of the line `\begin{longtable}{| *{3}{>{$}c<{$}} | }`?

Comment: @minthao_2011 - If all four columns contain math material that should be centered, just replace `*{3}` with `*{4}`.

Comment: When my document has two types three columns and four columns, I fell, there is array does not align center. In this Comment, I can not up my pictures.

Comment: @minthao_2011 - I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. If you have arrays, you need two separate environments, be they `array` or `longtable`.

Comment: If  I want to have one column. Please help me

Comment: @minthao_2011 - How should the numbers in the single column by arranged? I.e., how should the nx3 matrix be vectorized?

Comment: Please help me. I have a very long array, some of them are `\[
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{9,12,15\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -14 & -5 & 2 \\
 -6 & 3 & 6 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{9,12,15\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -14 & -2 & 5 \\
 -8 & 4 & 8 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{9,12,15\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -14 & 2 & 5 \\
 -8 & -4 & 8 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{9,12,15\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -14 & 2 & 5 \\
 -6 & 6 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
\]
` I want to use your code with 4 colums.

Comment: The first colum is  `\{9,12,15\}` ...

Comment: @minthao_2011 - Please post a new query, with well-formatted code.

Comment: Yes. I will post. Please help me.

Comment: I have just posted.

Comment: @Mico If I want to have a row with The order, coordinates of A,  coordinates of B,  coordinates of C. How can I define and where is put it?

Comment: @toandhsp - I'm afraid I don't understand your objective. Please post a new query, in which you lay out all formatting needs.

Comment: @Mico Like this picture.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=177RPpyz1RxlYwqGARfVSUtAyKeTG1qPV

Comment: @toandhsp - I'm at a location today that's behind a firewall that disables all access to google drive. Sorry. If you post a *new query*, it'll be seen by many more people. By all means, provide a link to the present posting if you feel it would be helpful to provide some context.