# How to convert this long array into a longtable with four colums?

Tags: longtable

I have a long array

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{array,longtable}\begin{document}
    \[
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}  \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -16 & 8 & 16 \\
 -6 & 12 & -12 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -16 & 8 & 16 \\
 -4 & 20 & 22 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -16 & 8 & 16 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & -12 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -16 & 16 & -8 \\
 -12 & -6 & 12 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -12 & -6 & 12 \\
 -4 & 10 & 28 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -12 & -6 & 12 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & -22 & 20 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \{18,24,30\} & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -12 & -6 & 12 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 16 & -16 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
 \]   
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Now I want to convert into the form [image] (I saw here [How to align long array?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219049/how-to-align-long-array/219073?noredirect=1#comment741450_219073))

```
\begin{longtable}{| *{4}{>{$}c<{$}} | }
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot 
\{18,24,30\} & (-16, 8, 16) & (-6, 12, -12) & (0,0,0)\\ 
\{18,24,30\} & (-16, 8, 16) & (-4, 20,22) & (0,0,0)\\ 
\{18,24,30\} & (-16, 8, 16) &  (0,0,0)  &  (6,-12,12)\\
\end{longtable}
```

In `longtable`:

- The left column of the array is the first column of the longtable 
  (from the left to right);
- In the right column, the first row is the second column of the longtable 
  (from the left to right); the second row is the third column of the longtable 
  and the third row is the fourth column of the longtable.

How can I convert it?

Comment: Please be more specific about how the rows of the new longtable are supposed to be formed from the row vectors and matrices. I'm asking because the third row of the new longtable seems to be generated according to a different method than what appears to apply for rows one and two.

Comment: @ Mico I am sory. Because I copied and pasted wrong.

Comment: No worries. Just post the "correct" code and screenshot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I also simplified your sub-arrays using pmatrix.  Just for fun I used TikZ to add tops and bottoms to the left and right sides.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{array,longtable}
    \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| *{2}{>{$}c<{$}} | }
\endfirsthead  % blank header on first page
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{(\emph{array continued from previous page})}
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{(\emph{array continued on next page})}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
% start of table
\multicolumn{2}{@{\tikz[overlay,xshift=.2pt,yshift=-4.3pt]{\draw (0,0) to[in=180,out=90] (5pt,5pt);}}c%
  @{\tikz[overlay,xshift=-.2pt,yshift=-4.3pt]{\draw (-5pt,5pt) to[in=90,out=0] (0,0);}}}{ }\\
\{18,24,30\} & \begin{pmatrix}
 -16 & 8 & 16 \\
 -6 & 12 & -12 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\{18,24,30\} & \begin{pmatrix}
 -16 & 8 & 16 \\
 -4 & 20 & 22 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\tikz[overlay,xshift=.2pt]{\draw (0,10pt) to[in=180,out=270] (5pt,5pt);}}c%
  @{\tikz[overlay,xshift=-.2pt]{\draw (-5pt,5pt) to[in=-90,out=0] (0,10pt);}}}{ }\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]